# Make a copy of a list but modify a field

Tags: kotlin, transformation

I have a list of `People`.

I want to change each person's status from `"active"` to `"not-active"`. I cannot modify the original data structure nor the original data.

```
fun changeClone(list: List<People>) {

    val newList = MutableList<People>()

    list.forEach { person ->
        //i feel there has to be an easier faster way to do this in kotlin
        val newPerson(person.name, ...., status = "not-active")
        newList.add(newPerson)
    }
    showUi(newList)
}
```

This is what a `Person` looks like:

```
data class Person(val name: String, ..., val status: String) {
}
```

I could make the `val status` into `var` but actually I am not supposed to modify the original data. So is there a Transformations trick I can do to make this easier?

Also all other data must be the same.

Comment: I didn't check, but `list.map { it.copy(status = "not-active") }` should work. See docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html ("Copying" part).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val newList = list.map { person ->
    person.copy(status = "not-active")
}
```